# dropbox upload only disable download or delete?

Tags: dropbox

I've installed `dropbox` on my linux `centos` 64 detected server , i need to take backup for some large files about 300GB this files always updated every month , also I've purchased dropbox `premium` account and i have 5 TB , every thing is fine until now , but dropbox is syncing file on server I/O , how i can make it upload only no download or delete ?

i found this script but how to add it to crontab -e ?

https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader

Comment: Read the GitHub readme?

Comment: i did , no clarify documentation or example !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the GitHub documentation](https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader/blob/master/README.md), you first need to download the script and make it executable:

```
curl "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader/master/dropbox_uploader.sh" -o /tmp/dropbox_uploader.sh
chmod +x /tmp/dropbox_uploader.sh
sudo mv /tmp/dropbox_uploader.sh /usr/local/bin/dropbox_uploader
```

Then run the uploader to configure (no prefix is needed as `/usr/local/bin` should be in your `PATH`):

```
dropbox_uploader
```

Once you have confiugred the script, you can add a command to crontab like so (example will trigger at midnight on the first of every month):

```
0 0 1 * * /usr/local/bin/dropbox_uploader upload [path_to_local_file] [path_to_remote_file]
```

Comment: you made my day